# How to use Generics or Reflection to show/hide fragments? Kotlin Android

Tags: android, generics, reflection, kotlin

I  have a fragment manager to show/hide fragments in my app. Right now when I want to show a fragment from any activity or fragment I call this method from the manager

```
 fun show(manager: FragmentManager, fragmentTag: String, container: Int, data: Any?): Companion {
        var fragment = manager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag)
        if (fragment != null) {
            manager.popBackStack(fragmentTag, 0)
        } else {
            addFragment(manager, getFragment(fragmentTag, manager, data)!!, container, fragmentTag)
        }
        return this
    }

 private fun getFragment(fragmentTag: String, manager: FragmentManager, data: Any?): Fragment? {
        when (fragmentTag) {
            MenuFragment.TAG -> return getMenuFragment(manager)
            TagsFragment.TAG -> return getTagsFragment(manager)
            ...
        }
        return null
    }
```

with return a fragment with a specific class

```
private fun getMenuFragment(manager: FragmentManager): Fragment {
        var fragment = manager.findFragmentByTag(MenuFragment.TAG) as MenuFragment?
        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = MenuFragment.newInstance()
        }
        return fragment
    }
```

I would like to have an strategy to avoid create one method every time I need to implement a new fragment, so I was thinking about generics or maybe reflection which I have never used before.

Is there any way to do this using reflection? or another better strategy?

Thanks for any help.

**Edit**

As I have one Activity and many fragments I finally extended FragmentManager to use it in every fragment.

```
inline fun <reified T : Fragment> FragmentManager.showFragment(tag: String, container: Int, args: Bundle? = null) {
    val clazz = T::class.java
    var fragment = findFragmentByTag(clazz.name)
    if (fragment != null) {
        this.popBackStack(tag, 0)
    } else {
        fragment = (clazz.getConstructor().newInstance() as T).apply {
            args?.let {
                it.classLoader = javaClass.classLoader
                arguments = args
            }
        }
        val transaction = this.beginTransaction()
        transaction.add(container, fragment as Fragment, tag)
        transaction.addToBackStack(tag)
        transaction.commit()
    }
}
```

call:

```
 activity!!.supportFragmentManager.showFragment<MenuFragment>(MenuFragment.TAG, R.id.container)
```

Comment: why don't use extension function for Fragment class?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? How can I improve it by creating an extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I correctly understood a question, you can write extension function for FragmentManager like this

```
inline fun <reified T : Fragment> FragmentManager.getFragment(args: Bundle? = null): Fragment {
    val clazz = T::class.java
    return findFragmentByTag(clazz.name) ?: return (clazz.getConstructor().newInstance() as T).apply {
        args?.let { 
            it.classLoader = javaClass.classLoader
            arguments = args
        }
    }
}
```

end then use it, e.g. in activity

```
val frag = supportFragmentManager.getFragment<MyFragment>()
```

where MyFragment - is your fragment class

Comment: Finally solved your way as I have only one activity and many fragments. I think this is the best approach to my goal. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

With Reflection provided that the fragment tag is the fully qualified name of the class provided using `MenuFragment::class.java.name`

```
private fun getFragment(fragmentTag: String, manager: FragmentManager, data: Any?): Fragment? {
    return manager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag) ?: getFragment(fragmentTag)
}

private fun getFragment(fragmentTag: String): Fragment? {
    val c = Class.forName(fragmentTag)
    return c.getMethod("newInstance").invoke(null) as Fragment?
}
```

Without Reflection

```
private fun getFragment(fragmentTag: String, manager: FragmentManager, data: Any?): Fragment? {
    return manager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag) ?: when (fragmentTag) {
        MenuFragment.TAG -> MenuFragment.newInstance()
        TagsFragment.TAG -> TagsFragment.newInstance()
        else -> null
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing is that I was trying to avoid this method not calling MenuFragment.newInstance(), I was thinking if could be possible to call T.newInstance() or "package.classname".newInstance() somehow.

Comment: I don't like reflection, but I tried crafting a solution using that. check the updated answer

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. ¿Why you don't like reflection? is it a bad practice?

Comment: @PabloR. yeah, it is a bad practice. first hardcoding the method name is super bad and can result in many undesired bugs as you have to take care when renaming the method or changing it in any place that you'll also need to handle it in the reflection code. Also, it has performance issues and lots of other issues because of the coupling and hardcoding names.